# Is there a way to check a function's arity in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

If I'm writing a function that gets passed another function, is there a way to check the arity of the function I'm passed, or pattern match against different arities? I could use is_function/2 to check for specific arities, but that would be an awkward way to get the number.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [`:erlang.fun_info/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#fun_info-1); it returns a bunch of information about a given function, including its arity:

```
iex> :erlang.fun_info(fn -> :ok end)[:arity]
0
iex> :erlang.fun_info(fn(_, _, _) -> :ok end)[:arity]
3
```

As the documentation I linked says, this function is mainly intended for debugging purposes but it can be used to determine the arity of a function.

Answer (score 10):

`:erlang.fun_info/1` is good for finding the arity if you have a reference to the function.

If you are trying to figure out what arities a function has, but don't have a reference to it (because the arity is a part of a functions identity) there are two methods.

If you want to know if it supports a specific arity `:erlang.function_exported/3` takes the module, function name (sans-arity), and arity:

`:erlang.function_exported(IO, :puts, 7) #=> false`

`:erlang.function_exported(IO, :puts, 2) #=> true`

If you want to know all of the arities a function supports you can use the module's `__info__` metadata function:

`:functions |> IO.__info__ |> Keyword.get_values(:puts) #=> [1,2]`